# Arrange objects by property with specific order using javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Is there a way that I could arrange an array of objects according to a certain property whose order is based on an external array (not just alphabetically, numerically, etc.)?

For example, let's say I have a temporary array:

```
var tempArray = ["b", "a", "d", "c"];
```

and an array of objects:

```
var objectArray = [
    { name: "John",
      section: "a" },
    { name: "Joe",
      section: "b" }, 
    { name: "Mike",
      section: "c" },
    { name: "Mark",
      section: "d"}
];
```

Can I rearrange **objectArray** so that the object order would follow the contents of **tempArray** hence returning objectArray as:

```
objectArray = [
    { name: "Joe",
      section: "b" },
    { name: "John",
      section: "a" }, 
    { name: "Mark",
      section: "d" },
    { name: "Mike",
      section: "c"}
];  // desired output
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can. Start from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
var sorted = objectArray.sort(function(a, b){
return tempArray.indexOf(a.section)-tempArray.indexOf(b.section)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). `Array#sort` sorts arrays, and you can give it a function to call that accepts two arguments, which are two entries to compare to determine which should be before the other. `Array#indexOf` tells you the index of an entry in the array. So if you use `Array#sort` on `objectArray`, and within your callback use `Array#indexOf` on `tempArray` to look up the indexes of each object's `section` property, then compare the indexes (or probably just subtract the second object's index from the first).